# OData service model for SAPUI5 App

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap

I'm trying to build a Odata model. 
My last successful time was following the guide to import the transparent table and create an EntitySet and implement CRUD function into the generated classes via ABAP workbench. 
This time I want to  create an OData model by importing the view (of some Master Data Tables) and not create an EntitySet. I just need to select the data to read. There is no need for inserts, modify or delete records. Can anyone please  show me if there are any guides that I can follow.

Answer (score 1):

To create an ODataModel you need an OData service. Depending on the OData service version (OData v2, OData v4) you can use a different ODataModel from the UI5 API.

- [OData v2](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel)
- [OData v4](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel)

Take a look at the constructor detail in these links for how to structure creating the ODataModel.

Answer (score 0):

I've been building these for a few years now, and I've noticed SEGW will not generate the DPC_EXT methods for your entity until you create the entity set.  So even if you're doing a read and not a query, you still need an entityset based on your entity if you want to do anything with it.

This guide might be helpful: http://www.bluefinsolutions.com/Blogs/Lindsay-Stanger/March-2014-%281%29/Building-your-first-simple-Gateway-service/